# WorkManager6.0 with SMP 2.3 deployment Issue

Tags: sybase, sap-smp

According to the official document I followed all the step to install SAP Mobile Platform (SMP) 2.3 (SP04) with WorkManager 6.0. After deploying the WorkManager6.0 via SCC, I am getting the following exception:

> Exception: 17:38:05 04/23/2014 : 159 (SSL Socket Error), SSL Socket Error (error:23076071:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_parse:mac verify failure, ), ..\Socket\openSSLsockets.cpp#406:OpenSSLcontext::OpenSSLcontext

I don't know what to do. Can anyone tell me how to fix this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in certificate. Here we need to create a certificate & have to install in client by renaming to .crt. & the other one need to deploy in the Server.